# Optimizing images for web usage

Tags: image, compression

I want to make my website as quick to load as possible. For this I want my images as small as I can get them. For icons I have found using PNG images with a small palette and some dithering is quite effective. I discovered this through the save for web feature in Photoshop. Unfortunately I don't have access to Photoshop anymore...

So... does anyone know of some good software (preferably free) which can *really* compress images? Preferably I'd want some previewing feature where you can tweak settings and see how they affect the size and the compressed image. What I want is pretty much the save for web feature in photoshop, without having go buy photoshop and go broke :p

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Smush.it](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/).

Answer (score 0):

[pngquant](http://pngquant.org) generates PNG-8 [better than Photoshop's Save for Web](http://pngquant.org/vsphotoshop.html).